# Is it possible to slice an array to sort of go backwards?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter

I have an array of longitude values that goes from 0 to 360 in increments of 1.

As an example:

```
longitude = np.arange(1,361,1)

print(longitude)


[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ... 360]
```

Is there a way to slice the longitude array so that I only include 1:20 and 275:360 in increments of 1?

So values 1 to 20 (1, 2, 3 ...) and values 275 to 360 (275, 276, 277...)

I tried something like:

```
test = longitude[1:10:275:360]
```

but from python's slicing method, it thinks it's [start:stop:step size]... and I get an error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-73-39c4381fa9dd>", line 1
    test = longitude[1:10:275:360]
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [np.r_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy-r):

```
 longitude[np.r_[1:10, 275:360]]
```

Output:

```
array([  2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10, 276, 277, 278, 279,
       280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292,
       293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305,
       306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318,
       319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331,
       332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344,
       345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357,
       358, 359, 360])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do [np.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

```
longitude = np.append(np.arange(1,21,1), np.arange(275,361,1))
print(longitude)
```

**Output:**

```
[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290
 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308
 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326
 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344
 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360]
```

Comment: Concatenate would be a better choice. That's what append uses under the hood anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
yourarray.splice(11, 276)
```